# How to disable TLS v1.1 in Nginx

Tags: nginx, ssl, cipher

It seems to be a straightforward configuration setting, but I cannot disable TLSv1.1.

**nginx.conf** in /etc/nginx:

> ssl_protocols TLSv1.2;

**Domain configuration** last_nginx.conf (changed via Plesk templates in nginxDomainVirtualHost.php):

```
ssl_protocols                TLSv1.2;    
ssl_ciphers                 ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:HIGH:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!RC4:!MD5:!PSK:!SRP:!CAMELLIA;

ssl_prefer_server_ciphers   on;
ssl_dhparam /etc/nginx/ssl/server.dh_pem;
```

Still the TLSv1.1 is enabled and, when tested with openssl returns this:

```
openssl s_client -tls1_1 -connect mydomain.com:443 < /dev/null

    New, TLSv1/SSLv3, Cipher is DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA
Server public key is 2048 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.1
    Cipher    : DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA
    Session-ID: E298E87276A0776AF736439AF260FE0F92B17330ED97D5F3C2F87CF02C3F75A8
```

What am I missing here? Why is TLSv1.1 still enabled though only TLSv1.2 was specified?

Any suggestions how to disable TLSv1.1?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is speculation as you did not post your fully (sanitized) configuration, but most likely have are using a shared `listen` block across multiple servers. Though the configuration syntax makes it seem possible, you actually cannot have disparate cipher specs across `server` blocks that share the same `listen`.

More specifically:

```
server {
   listen 443 ssl;
   server_name tls.example.com;
}

server {
   listen 443 ssl;
   server_name tls12.example.com;
   ssl_protocols TLSv1.2;
}
```

If you were to curl tls12.example.com here you would find that it has 1.1 support. However if you were to add the same restriction to the tls.example.com `server`, only 1.2 would be supported.

The only real fix is to use a dedicated IP for the restriction, or ensure that all `server` blocks for that (ip,port) combination have the same SSL cipher settings.

Side note: The discussion above also applies to enabling/disabling HTTP/2.